# Ordering issues with self join

Tags: sql, self-join

I have 2 tables. Reviewer with 2 columns (rID, name) and Rating with 3 columns (rID, mID, stars). I want to select all pairs of reviewers such that both reviewers gave a rating to the same movie. The query should return the names of both reviewers, eliminate duplicates and return the names of each pair in alphabetical order. My code is:

```
select distinct Re1.name, Re2.name 
from Reviewer Re1, Rating R1, Rating R2, Reviewer Re2
where R1.mID = R2.mID
and Re1.rID = R1.rID
and Re2.rID = R2.rID
and R1.rID <> R2.rID 
group by R1.mid
order by Re1.name
```

It produces this:

```
Ashley White        Chris Jackson
Chris Jackson       Brittany Harris
Elizabeth Thomas    Daniel Lewis
James Cameron       Elizabeth Thomas
Mike Anderson       Sarah Martinez
```

... while the expected result is:

```
Ashley White        Chris Jackson
Brittany Harris     Chris Jackson
Daniel Lewis        Elizabeth Thomas
Elizabeth Thomas    James Cameron
Mike Anderson       Sarah Martinez
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Imagine A, B, C in your data so you join will result in `A->B`, `A-->C`, and `C-->A` and `C-->B` (among others) by using <> you eliminate the A-->A but you keep the C-->A which is a duplicate.  so by using `>` or `<` instead of `<>` you eliminate the duplication; which should resolve the ordering issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `R1. r ID < R2. r ID` instead of `<>`.

This way you can control the order based on `ID`.

If the order is supposed to be based on name then keep your original `ON` conditions and **add** `R1. name < R2. name`.

Comment: While I believe this will resolve the problem.  It would help to see an explanation as to why this would work and why there was a problem int eh first place.

Comment: Same result, unfortunately.

Comment: @Levente See my expanded answer

Comment: You're a genius! Just for the record, the whole WORKING code here: `select  distinct Re1.name, Re2.name
from Reviewer Re1, Rating R1, Rating R2, Reviewer Re2
where R1.mID = R2.mID
and Re1.rID = R1.rID
and Re2.rID = R2.rID
and R1.rID <> R2.rID
and Re1.name < Re2.name
group by R1.mid
order by Re1.name`